# Exporting dataframe - used reduceRegion to sample an image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sampling

I am trying to sample the Global Forest Change dataset using randomly drawn points and the reduceRegion function. The way I construct this is:

```
var sampledPoints = gfc2014_c.reduceRegions({
  collection:points,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
});
```

Where `gfc2014_c` is the GFC datset cropped to sub-Saharan Africa and points are my randomly drawn points. The entire code is [here.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fbb886ba8849d5bde2a429edb66117a5)

I was aiming for a large sample of 1 million pixels. When I try to export in chunks (even chunks as small as 5,000) I get the following error:

```
Error: image.reduceRegions: Computed value is too large.
```

What am I doing wrong? I know the GFC dataset is really large, but it must be possible, right?

Comment: Interesting problem. I'll tinker with it over the weekend. In the meantime, try: 1) preping your point sample with all the joins etc and export it as an asset, then import it to do the region reduction; 2) don't clip the image data being reduced; 3) try mapping `reduceRegion` over the point sample instead of using `reduceRegions` (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging?hl=en#reduceregion-vs.-reduceregions)

Comment: Thank you Justin. I just tried your third suggestion, currently attempting an export of 100,000 observations. Fingers crossed!

Comment: What was the outcome - keep me posted.

Comment: Mapping - reduce region sped up the process a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that mapping `reduceRegion()` resulted in better performance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Justin's comment above and the [part of the debugging guide he directed me to](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging?hl=en#reduceregion-vs.-reduceregions), I tried the following:

```
var sampledPoints = points.map(function(feature) {
  return feature.set(gfc2014.reduceRegion({
    reducer: 'mean',
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
  }));
});
```

This seems to have worked: I can now export a chunk of 100,000 observations in 5 hours. Thank you Justin!